# Query do not return all fields

Tags: php, doctrine

I've a query to get all `Schools` with a `JOIN` to `District` table.

```
SELECT * FROM School LEFT JOIN Dicstrict ON School.school_number = District.school_number ORDER BY School.school_number
```

If I execute this query in PHPMyAdmin I get a result which look like:

```
school_number    name    school_number
12345            abc     12345
67890            def     null
63712            ghj     null
```

If I execute this on `doctrine` with dbal in `silex`:

```
$stmt = $this->app['db']->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM School LEFT JOIN Dicstrict ON School.school_number = District.school_number ORDER BY School.school_number');
$filteredData = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $filteredData[] = $row;
}
var_dump($filteredData);
```

I get this result

```
school_number    name
12345            abc
null             def
null             ghj
```

I have no ideas what happen and how can I solve this issue. Does someone else has the same issue?

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: There are two fields with the same name.  You can't have two fields with the same name in PHP associative arrays.  You'll either have to use indexed arrays (and put up with the mess that can result if the column layout changes) or alias at least one of the fields with AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two fields with name `school_number`, therefore one is overwritten by the other on PHP side while fetching a row.

Associative arrays cannot have the same key twice.